# Does SELECT * FROM (...union...) AS tablexyz create a temp table?

Tags: sql, union, temp-tables

Does a query such as this create a temp table? or is it a one time use within the query?

```
SELECT A
FROM
(
    SELECT A, B FROM TableA
    UNION
    SELECT A, B FROM TableB
) AS tbl
WHERE B > 'some value'
```

I am using psql, and snowflake

Comment: postgres, mysql, sql server, oracle? which engine are you using?

Comment: Updated the question with what sql I am using. I am unsure what you mean by engine.

Comment: ti will obviously create tables, but not "public" like a table created manually, infact probably if you run it again just after having run it, you will see an increase of performance

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Would I be able to do a follow up query such as 
```SELECT * from tbl```

Comment: You have to create a local temporary view if you want to do that

Comment: psql <> snowflake. Please pick on or the other and then _tag_ it correctly

Comment: A query doesn't create schema objects, but most likely an internal table-like rowset will be created for the `UNION`

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not create a *temp table*.

It does, however, materialize the rows.  I'm pretty sure it does this in all databases.  The use of `union` requires removing duplicates.  The duplication removal would typically be done using a sorting or hashing algorithm.

In both these cases, the data is going to be written into intermediate storage.

However, the extra metadata that is used for temporary tables would not typically be written.  This would just be "within-a-query" temporary space.

Comment: If the tables are small enough and fit into memory, I don't think any modern DBMS would actually materialize them for the UNION, e.g. by using a hash algorithm to perform the distinct

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, a temporary table does not get created.  By "temporary table," I mean a file on disk, with a `relfilenode` entry in `pg_class`, that exists for the duration of the `psql` session.  A "table" is created in memory for the purposes of the query execution, but it's not a "table" in the sense that you can query from it (it's more of a data structure).

What you're asking about is basically how Postgres handle subqueries--subqueries are evaluated and materialized, then stored into memory/cache for future reference.  If you take a look at `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` as you repeat your query 2-3 times, you'll see that a subquery node gets generated, and subsequent calls to the query will lead to `shared buffers hit:...`, indicating that the previous calls were cached for faster future access.